# Android: How to center an included view?

Tags: android, android-studio, include, center

as the title states i do have an view which looks as the following:

```
attachment_main.xml

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/Frage_attachment"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:text="Frage Attachment "
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.609"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.343" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_attachment"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:text="OK"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.214"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.572" />
```

This view is included in a new view as the following:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/idAttachment"
        layout="@layout/attachment_main"
        android:layout_width="549dp"
        android:layout_height="808dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

**Question:** In the new view, i would like to put the content of the include at the center of the screen. How do i make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You only need  to have the next

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/idAttachment"
        layout="@layout/attachment_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Please not use width with fix, because you can have different resolution

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
```

Comment: Didn't fully work out, the second part with `android:laout_width="match_parent"` Should it be put into the original attachment_main.xml?

Comment: yes , they are only the properties, but it should be included in tag